# SQL VIEW - add column based on value of another

Tags: sql-view

I would like to create a view that selects ALL columns in a table, then creates/adds an additional "columnX" based on the value of another column in that same table.

For example if [column1] IS NULL, I would like [columnX] = 0 (zero)
and if [column1] IS NOT NULL, I would like [columnX] = [column1]

I think this should be simple, but I cannot seem to find the solution.
Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case when col1 is null then 0 else col1 end as COLUMNX

Comment: Thanks!  But, where do I add this into my SELECT statement?

Comment: just add it as if it is a column in your select list... like this
Select cola, colb, case when col1 is null then 0 else col1 end as COLUMNX from yourtable

Comment: glad to here it... BTW you can also "stack" the when part of the case like this case when <condit> then <val> else <val> when ... when ... else <val> end... so it can be very useful for a lot of things